# nginx proxy_pass on / giving 404 with go app

Tags: go, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've a simple go app which serves html via nginx proxy_pass. My issue is that I get a 404 on the / , the other  directives work fine. Any ideas ?

nginx config file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

 location  / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
      }

 location /codcall {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
   }
 location /codcall-dev {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
   }
}
```

my go app routes

```
func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/codcall", indexHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/codcall-dev", indexHandler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8001", nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Must have been a mixup somewhere between loaded configs and what I thought was loaded. I rebooted my vps and double checked everything config wise and its working now.